# Python df.dropna(inplace=True) vs df = df.dropna() leading to different results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

df.dropna(inplace=True) modifies df in the first screenshot while df = df.dropna() does not modify df in the second screenshot.

I would prefer to use df = df.dropna() as I thought the two lines of code perform the same calculation and the inplace=True call is being deprecated in later versions of python.

**Can someone explain why df = df.dropna() does not work?**

Screenshot 1

[image: Code with df.dropna(inplace=True)]

Screenshot 2

[image: Identical code with df = df.dropna()]

Comment: What is `C` in these screenshots?

Comment: As you've explained yourself, `df.dropna()` does not modify an existing dataframe, but rather returns a new one. This means that your call to `df.dropna` inside yout function won't affect the dataframe directly (whose reference you stored in the `portfolio_list`), but rather return a modified version of them. Currently you're returning this modified version from your function, but not doing anything with them (in the line `df = daily_return_calc(df)`).

Comment: As an aside using `inplace` param in pandas is discouraged and earmarked for deprecation in the future

Answer (score 1):

If `portfolio_list` is a list of `df`'s, it'd be better to `map(dropna)` on the list, rather than iterating through the list and attempting (unsuccessfully) to alter to the elements in the list during iteration (which is not advised). I.e.,

```py
portfolio_list = [*map(lambda df_x: df_x.dropna(), portfolio_list)]
```

or something like that. But a list comprehension would be even better:

```py
portfolio_list = [df.dropna() for df in portfolio_list]
```

probably.

And to include your other function, it'd just be:

```py
portfolio_list = [daily_return_calc(df) for df in portfolio_list]
```

and you would be able to use your version of the function without the `inplace` parameter on the `dropna` line, because you're *collecting* the copies of the dataframe made via the list comprehension and simultaneous reassignment to `portfolio_list`.

Comment: Using `apply` won't work because it will try to apply `daily_return_calc` to each column of `df`, while `daily_return_calc` expects the whole `df`. You can use `pipe`  `[df.pipe(daily_return_calc) for df in portfolio_list]` or more commonly  just `[daily_return_calc(df) for df in portfolio_list]`.

Comment: @HarryPlotter, d'oh, thank you, yes of course. The answer has been corrected